# "Status is Invalid" - Active Record - Rails 4.1 -> 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm working on upgrading a **Ruby 2.2.2 (Rails 4.1)** app to **Ruby 2.5.7 (Rails 5.2)** and for a couple of models I'm getting some errors

From searching around, it sounds like there are some generic activerecord validation rules / messages?  The messages are:

```
Status is invalid
User is invalid`
```

I am a novice at best with Ruby - so any suggestions on the best way to work through this error are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rails 5, whenever a `belongs_to` association is defined, it is required to have the associated record present by default. That means, compared to Rails 4, each `belongs_to :foo` association basically adds internally a `validate :foo, presence: true` to the code too.

You have two choices:

- Follow the new Ruby on Rails conventions and fix your tests by adding all required associated objects to the models.
- Switch back to the old behavior for these kinds of associations by adding `, optional: true` to each `belongs_to :foo` line in your code.

There is actually the third option to switch off this behavior in the whole application, by adding a line like this to your `application.rb`

```
Rails.application.config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = true
```

But that means your application will not follow Ruby on Rails conventions and defaults anymore and IMHO this ofter leads to problems with a later update.

Therefore my advice is: Fix your tests now and only make those associations optional that are really optional from the user's point of view – this might take a bit longer but causes certainly less trouble in the future.